# ChartJS using AJAX call to retrieve data isn't rendering visualization

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, chart.js

I don't have any issue creating visualizations from static datasets using ChartJS, but when I use data retrieved via an AJAX call, the visualization fails to render. No errors are being thrown, and my data is structured identically.

Here's my javascript:

```
var ctx = $('#myChart');

function drawDonut(){

  $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "url",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(data){

      var myDoughnutChart = new Chart (ctx, {
        type: 'doughnut',
        data: data,
        animation:{
          animateScale:true
        }
      });
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    drawDonut();
});
```

Here's how the AJAX data is constructed:

```
var data = {
   labels: ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'orange', 'yellow'],
   datasets: {
      data: [12, 15, 17, 19, 202],
      }
}
```

I've tried including var ctx both inside the 'drawDonut' function and outside as shown. I've stored 'drawDonut' as a variable and called it separately. Neither worked. Any thoughts?

**EDIT:**

Forgot to mention that the iframe from ChartJS is being appended to the DOM, just not the actual chart.

Comment: Are you sure your ajax call is synchronous ?

Comment: I'm not, but I've tried calling it both with $(document).ready and on a click event post-page load just to see if that was the issue - it's not.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the data that comes back is a JSON object and not just a JSON string. In other words, try `data = JSON.parse(data)` which may solve the problem.

Comment: Nope, that's throwing an exception. We're dealing with a valid object. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

`data.datasets` should be an array of objects, you have a single object.

I get the same result (no graph drawn) if I remove the array `[]` from one of mine that normally uses this manually created structure within an ajax success function:

```
data: {
    labels: ajaxData.Labels,
    datasets: [{
        label: ajaxData.Sets[0].Label,
        data: ajaxData.Sets[0].Data,
        backgroundColor: colourScheme.seventyPercent,
        hoverBackgroundColor: colourScheme.opaque,
        borderColor: colourScheme.white,
        borderWidth: 2
    }]
}
```